# Django | Вывести дерево связанных объектов

Tags: django, django-orm

Требуется помощь по Django.

Имеется модель:

```
class Match(models.Model):
    date_time = models.DateTimeField('Дата начала', auto_now_add=True)
```

```
class Forecast(models.Model):
    date_time = models.DateTimeField('Когда опубликован', auto_now_add=True)
    match = models.ManyToManyField(to='matches.Match')
```

```
class ForecastChoice(models.Model):
    date_time = models.DateTimeField('Когда опубликован', auto_now_add=True)
    forecast = models.ForeignKey(Forecast, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='choice')
```

Каким образом составить запрос, чтобы в шаблоне страницы Match вывести дерево связанных объектов таким образом:

```
Match
--Forecast
----ForecastChoice
----ForecastChoice
----ForecastChoice
--Forecast
----ForecastChoice
----ForecastChoice
----ForecastChoice
--Forecast
----ForecastChoice
----ForecastChoice
----ForecastChoice
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В контекст передаешь "matches".

```
context = {"matches": Match.objects.all()}
```

А в шаблоне вот так пишешь:

```html
{%for match in matches %}
    <div class=match>
    {% for forecast in match.forecast_set.all %}
        <div class="forecast">
        {% for choiсe in forecast.choiсe.all %}
            <div class="choiсe">{{choiсe.date_time}}</div>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Должно сработать.
Совет: related_name лучше писать во множественном числе.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!